# Making alexa skill accessible to private users (select users)

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created a skill for an enterprise that has access to their private and sensitive data. Now they want to access it using multiple devices. But I cannot see the option to host the skill for private use or for select users, but only host for public or beta testing options is there. Whereas beta testing has its own limitations and can be live for max of 90 days. So, what are the available options to solve this. Or is there any alternative. Please whatever solution or suggestion you have, that will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing your skill as a private skill is currently only available for Alexa for Business accounts. Alexa for Business is currently only available in the US, but also still available for short period of time, since it will be retired soon and be replaced for another product, Alexa Smart properties. Please find below the relevant information about both:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/a4b/latest/ag/what-is.html → about what Alexa for Business is and when this will deprecated
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-smart-properties/about-alexa-smart-properties.html → about Alexa Smart Properties

Therefore, if you wish to keep your skill available for a restricted audience only, the only solution is starting a new beta test every 90 days and manually invite your users to use your skill, or giving access to your Alexa Console.